# IE bug when using RTL direction for floated elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer

My page looks great on FireFox, Chrome, and Safari. But on IE it seems to be extra margin between floated divs when RTL direction is used. When I remove "direction:rtl" it works fine on IE.

Here is my CSS of the 2 adjacent DIVs. Any idea? Thanks

```
#box5{
    position:relative;
    background:#FFF;
    float:right;
    width:436px; height:203px; overflow:hidden;
    padding:30px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin:20px 105px 0 70px;
    direction:rtl;
}

#box6{
    position:relative;
    background:#FFF;
    float:right;
    width:436px; height:203px; overflow:hidden;
    padding:30px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin:20px 0 0 70px;
    direction:rtl;
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE?  Do you have a demo?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I removed the left margin and it worked. It seems that left margin should not be used with `direction:rtl`.

Comment: For me it was margin-right that caused the bug to appear, so it seems any margin (left or right) should be removed.